# How do you detect when the user drags their finger over a specific object

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to detect when the user drags their finger over a specific object, and run code when that happens. I have a grid made of many squares and the user will drag their character, an ImageView, across the grid, sort of like a maze but with consequences for breaking off the path. I need to detect when the user's finger, or character, crosses over any of those squares, then, run a function based on that square's color. That function should only run one time when the user collides with that square, *instead of* continuously for as long as the character is over it. Hopefully this image of the app and the grid will help too. [The grid for the app is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHxvc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue and created my own system of hitboxes. Here is my function for it. The function should be called repeatedly every moment you want to check for the collisions, or loop the function and just call it once at the start of the code. However, there is still one unsolved issue. I still can't figure out how to detect the color of that tile and run specific functions based on that color(which can change). And I might need 91 duplicates of this function since I have 91 tiles that need these hitboxes. Here is what I came up with anyways:

```
private fun collideDetect2() {
        val warningColor = "#FF8C00" // part of a testing tool to help test my hardcoded hitboxes
        val fixColor = "#00ED8E"

        val playerX = player.x
        val playerY = player.y
        val tileX = tile69.x // tile69 is one of the objects I need to detect collision for on the grid of squares
        val tileY = tile69.y 
        if (playerX <= (tileX + 155f)) {
            if(playerX >= (tileX - 85f)) {
                println("X collision detected.")                            //helped with debugging and testing
                println("player's X is $playerX and tile's X is $tileX")    //helped with debugging and testing
                if (playerY >= (tileY + 75f)) {
                    if(playerY <= (tileY + 275f)) {
                        println("Y collision detected.")
                        println("player's Y is $playerY and tile's Y is $tileY")
                        if (!activated) { // activated was defined at the top of the file, "var activated = false" This variable allows the function to only run once when the collision is detected until the objects are no longer overlapping, instead of running every moment they are overlapping while it is being checked
                            activated = true
                            highlightRandomTiles()    // the function I want it to run when the collision is detected for this specific tile
                            when ((1..2).random()) { // testing tool to tell me when the player image has overlapped. without the "activated" variable, it would tell me every single moment the hitbox was overlapping
                                2 -> {
                                    tile69.setBackgroundColor(warningColor.toColorInt())
                                }                                  
                                1 -> {
                                    tile69.setBackgroundColor(fixColor.toColorInt())
                                } 

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        activated = false // allows the code to know the player has left the hitbox so the function will run again next time the collision occurs. Might not need this in all 4 places tho...
                    }
                }
                else {
                    activated = false
                }
            }
            else {
                activated = false
            }
        }
        else {
            activated = false
        }
    }
```